# dojo.connect not working for onClick event (in Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dojo, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

I added `dojo.connect` statement like this,

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId(this._paramsForm), "onChange", this, "_handleUpdate");
```

At this point, when I browser debug and check the values, `this._paramsForm` has valid values.
But when the event is getting triggered, `onChange` function is not being called. There must be some problem in the `dojo.connect` statement, but not able to trace it.

Tried this one as well, No luck :(

```
dojo.connect(this._paramsForm, "onChange", this, "_handleUpdate");
```

Referred this link as well, no luck
[dojo.connect won't connect 'onclick' with button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008406/dojo-connect-wont-connect-onclick-with-button)

But the same thing is working absolutely fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Please help me to fix this issue!

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are registering the event handler is wrong - try this:

```
require('dojo/_base/lang', 'dojo/on');

on(this._paramsForm, "change", lang.hitch(this, _handleUpdate));
```

Note that in the lastest versions, the prefix 'on' has been dropped - you just need to use 'click', 'change' etc; as the event names. lang.hitch - ensures that _handleUpdate is executed in the context of 'this'.

If you are using a older version of dojo (< 1.7), then the code will be similar:

```
dojo.connect(this._paramsForm, "onChange", dojo.hitch(this, _handleUpdate));
```